# php SimpleXML check if a child exists

Tags: php, simplexml

`A->b->c` might exist but `c` might not exist. How do I check it?

Comment: Please select a new answer

Answer (score -26, accepted):

```
if($A->b->c != null) //c exists
```

If `c` does not exist, its value will be `null` (or, to be more precise, it will have no value). Note, however, that for this to work, both `A` and `b` need to not be `null`. Otherwise, PHP will throw an error (I think).

Comment: This isn't a great idea. c will be an empty object if the node does not exist, which isn't the same as NULL.

Comment: To add to what @spikyjt said, if node c doesn't exist in $A->b, an empty SimpleXMLElement is returned.  The valid instance of SimpleXMLElement is not null; that expression always evaluates true.

Answer (score 133):

It might be better to wrap this in an `isset()`

```
if(isset($A->b->c)) { // c exists
```

That way if `$A` or `$A->b` don't exist... it doesn't blow up.

Comment: This seemed neater than the other answers, but actually SimpleXMLElement returns and empty SimpleXMLElement object for any requested node that doesn't exist. So the empty() method seems like the best route.

Comment: also, `c` may be optional but `A` and `b` may be required, so I may actually want to get an exception if they are not defined - easy way to check document's integrity

Comment: @spikyjt `isset()` is the best route to check if the node exists. You can use `empty()` if you need to check whether the node exists AND has something inside it, i.e. between `>` and `<` (either text or child nodes). If you need just to check for the existence of the node then `empty()` won't do. For example, `empty()` will return you `true` for this node `<b a="zzz"></b>`

Comment: @CITBL you are correct, `empty()` is not much use. It is important to be aware however, that if there is no `c` element, `isset($A->c) === false`, but `$A->c` returns an empty SimpleXMLElement. So with `$c = $A->c;`, then `isset($c) === true` (i.e. `$c !== null` even though that might be expected).

Answer (score 41):

SimpleXML always return Object. If there is no child, empty object is returned.

```
if( !empty($a->b)){
  var_dump($a->b);
}
```

Comment: Apparently this is a feature and not a bug. And it is very important to note this. Accessing a child of the object will create it if it does not exist.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, would have saved me some time and frustration :-)

Comment: Wrong answer. Because `empty()` returns `true` even if the node exists but has no content. For example, in your code sample, if `$a` contains this: `<xml><b a="zzz"/></xml>` then `empty($a->b)` will return `true`. Therefore that's not a reliable way to check if a node exists. You can use `empty()` though if you need something inside a node, i.e. between `>` and `<`, and not interested in the node without content

Answer (score 10):

The answer by @null is correct - the simplest way to do this is with `isset`

```php
if (isset($A->b->c)) { /* c exists */ }
```

However, the reasons for it are not obvious (to me at least), and there's a fair bit of misinformation on this page. It took me a while to understand it properly so I wanted to share what I learned.

As some people have pointed out, when you access a non-existent child of a SimpleXMLElement, what you get is actually an 'empty' SimpleXMLElement, as opposed to false or null.

So for example if b doesn't exist:

```
$b = $A->b; // $b is now an empty SimpleXMLElement
$b->getName(); // returns an empty string
isset($b); // returns true
```

So you might think that using `isset` to test for the existence of children is not going to work, because if the child doesn't exist, we still get an empty SimpleXMLObject, so `isset` is bound to return true.

But in fact it doesn't:

```
isset($A->b); // returns false
```

This was pretty surprising to me! The reason is that `isset` is not a regular function but a PHP language construct.  When you call `isset($A->b)` PHP does not first calculate `$A->b` and then pass the result as an argument to `isset()`. Instead the behaviour when isset is called on an inaccessible object property is to call the `__isset()` overloading method on the class (as explained here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset)

So the author of the class can control the result of `isset($A->b)` independently from the result of `$b = $A->b`. In the case of SimpleXMLElement, they set it up so that `isset($A->b)` returns true if b exists and false otherwise - exactly what we need for testing the existence of a child element.

One further footnote to this - the original question asked about testing the existence of `$A->b->c`. Using `isset($A->b->c)` works perfectly for this as well, even if the intermediate b doesn't exist. I think what's happening here is that PHP first does `$A->b`, and if b doesn't exist, it gets an empty SimpleXMLElement, then it calls `__isset('c')` on that empty SimpleXMLElement to get the final result of `isset($A->b->c)`.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by using the `children()` function and doing a `count()` on it, ignoring an PHP error if there are no children by putting an @ before the count-call. This is stupid, but it works:

```
$identification = $xml->identification;
if (@count($identification->children()) == 0)
  $identification = $xml->Identification;
```

I hate this..

Comment: You are completely right (that's why I said 'I hate this...'), but when you know that whatever error happens, you want it to be ignored, then this is fine.

Answer (score 8):

After some experimentation, I've discovered that the only reliable method of checking if a node exists is using `count($xml->someNode)`.

Here's a test case: https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/6262156

Answer (score 4):

If you have PHP 5.3, you can just use `$a->count()`. Otherwise, scippie's solution using `@count($a->children())` works well. I find I don't need the @ but older PHP implementations may need it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the currently accepted one is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Using `if(isset($A->b){`
gave me issues, so I tried
`if($A->b){`
and it worked!

Comment: `count` and cast to boolean are the two ways that makes sense.  Using `if` as you describe is the shortest way to cast to boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Method xpath returns array of matched elements or false

```
if(false !== $A->xpath('b/c')) { ...
```

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: No, the docs indicate it returns FALSE if there's an error, not if the path returned no results.

Comment: Tested this, @Brian is correct, it will only return false when an error occurs. Do not use this check, it will always return a (empty) node.

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
var_dump(count($xml->node));
```

Comment: In PHP7.2 they added a warning when counting something that does not implement Countable interface. So, this should be taken into account and better use isset() over count()

Answer (score 2):

Using xpath:

```
function has_child(?\SimpleXMLElement $parent, string $xpathToChild)
{
    return isset($parent) && !empty($parent->xpath('('.$xpathToChild.')[1]'));
}
```

where `$parent` is an indirect or direct parent of the child node to check and `$xpathToChild` is an xpath of the child relative to `$parent`.

`()[1]` is because we don't want to select all the child nodes. One is enough.

To check if $a->b->c exists:

```
if(has_child($a,'b/c')) { //...
```

You can also check for attributes. To check if the node `c` has the `t` attribute.

```
if(has_child($a,'b/c/@t')) { //...
```

Answer (score 1):

The 3 ways I can confirm work in PHP 5.5.23 were using `isset()` `count()` or `empty()`

Here is a script to show the results from each:

https://gist.github.com/mchelen/306f4f31f21c02cb0c24

Answer (score 1):

I use a helper function to check if a node is a valid node provided as a parameter in function.

```
private static function isValidNode($node) {
  return isset($node) && $node instanceof SimpleXMLElement && !empty($node);
}
```

Usage example:

```
public function getIdFromNode($node) {
  if (!self::isValidNode($node)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (int)$node['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share my experience.  Running on 5.4 I tried testing with 'isset' and 'empty' but neither worked for me.  I ended up using **is_null**.

```
if(!is_null($xml->scheduler->outterList->innerList)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Name Spaces

Be aware that if you are using name spaces in your XML file you will need to include those in your function calls when checking for children otherwise it will return ZERO every time:

```
if ($XMLelement->children($nameSpace,TRUE)->count()){
    //do something here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for earlier versions, but as at PHP 8.0, using the following one-line function:

```
function elementExists(?SimpleXMLElement $element) : bool {
  return is_null($element)?false:@count($element);
}

$A = new SimpleXMLElement('<A><b><c/></b></A>');  // doc contains c
$B = new SimpleXMLElement('<B><b/></B>');         // doc does not contain c 
$C = new SimpleXMLElement('<C><x><c/></x></C>');  // doc contains c but different heirarchy

print '$A contains ->b->c : ' . (elementExists($A->b->c)?"true":"false") . PHP_EOL;
print '$B contains ->b->c : ' . (elementExists($B->b->c)?"true":"false") . PHP_EOL;
print '$C contains ->b->c : ' . (elementExists($C->b->c)?"true":"false") . PHP_EOL;
```

returns

```
$A contains ->b->c : true
$B contains ->b->c : false
$C contains ->b->c : false
```

ie. correctly determines whether or not **c** exists and is in the required location.

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
if($A->b->c && $A->b->c != '')
```