# How can I update children, grouped with id "X", using simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, updatexml

I am new to `simplexml` so forgive me if I get some terms mixed up :)

I have the following xml file stored at: `js/data.xml`:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <id>2011</id>
    <posX>12</posX>
    <posY>29</posY>
    <title>Senior Developer</title>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>2022</id>
    <posX>45</posX>
    <posY>87</posY>
    <title>Test22 text</title>
  </user>
</users>
```

I have a php file with working code to add more users:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("js/data.xml");
    $user = $xml->addChild('user');
    $user->addChild('id',2022);
    $user->addChild('posX',34);
    $user->addChild('posY',67);
    $user->addChild('title','Test33 text');
    // Store new XML code in data.xml
    $xml->asXML("js/data.xml");
    echo $xml->asXML();
```

This will add a new user into the file. So far so good, no problems here.

If you take a good look at the code, you'll see that this new user I want to add has the same id (2022) as a user in the xml file. This is the same person, so in this case I don't want to add him, but update him. This is where the problems start.

To update him I first need to check if the ID exists. I did some google-ing and searched this site and found a solution given here: [php SimpleXML check if a child exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560827/php-simplexml-check-if-a-child-exist) Problem is, I can't get it to work.

This is the modified code of my php file:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("js/data.xml");

//from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560827/php-simplexml-check-if-a-child-exist
if (isset($xml->user->id->2022)) { // c exists
   echo "test";
} else { //else add it
   $user = $xml->addChild('user');
   $user->addChild('id',2022);
   $user->addChild('posX',45);
   $user->addChild('posY',87);
   $user->addChild('title','Test33 text');
}
// Store new XML code in data.xml
$xml->asXML("js/data.xml");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

So here I try to check if the id exists. If so: `echo` something, else add the person. Unfortunally, when I run this code I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'
```

Anyone has an idea what I do wrong here?

Second problem I have is updating the children (`posX`, `posY` and `title`) if the `id` exists (ofcourse ONLY the children grouped with this id) . That part of the code needs to be where the test echo is now. I couldn't find a working solution on this site or google using simplexml. Does anyone has an idea how to do this?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather use `xpath()` to select a `<user>`by `<id>`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$id         = "2022";
list($user) = $xml->xpath("/users/user[id = '$id']") + [NULL];
```

Now check `$user`. If your XML has the above ID, `$user` will contain the `SimpleXML` element.
If not, `$user` will be `NULL`.

```
if (!$user) {
    // create new user
} else  {
    $user->title = "updated!";
}
```

Please note that the `[NULL]` at the end of line 3 requires PHP >= 5.4, if you don't have it, use:

```
list($user) = $xml->xpath("/users/user[id = '$id']") + array(NULL);
```

see it working: https://eval.in/236618

Comment: This worked great, thanks for the explanation and examples. These helped a lot in understanding it all

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'
> ```
>
> Anyone has an idea what I do wrong here?

This is quite simple to answer, the main part of the error message is *"syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER"*.

*Parse error* means PHP could not understand the code you've written. That's normally a sign of a typographical mistake (aka *syntax error* for computers). PHP then tells you with what it had an error with: *unexpected T_LNUMBER* of which `T_LNUMBER` is a token name for *long number*, long as in integer, not specifically long as in way.

```
// from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560827/php-simplexml-check-if-a-child-exist
if (isset($xml->user->id->2022)) 
                          ^^^^
```

That is this number there. In PHP to access a field, it needs to start with a letter in the range of A-Z or a-z at that place, not with a letter from a different range like 0-9 as you have it there.

You copied the code too quickly from the [existing answer over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1562158/367456) most likely because you want to do two things at once:

```
$idExists = isset($xml->user->id);
$idIs2022 = $idExists && trim($xml->user->id) == 2022;
```

The first line of code stores the result of whether or not the XML parsed in the **SimpleXMLElement** `$xml` has the first *user* element containing a child-element named *id*. It still will fail if there is no *user* element at all.

The second line compares the trimmed text value of that element with the numeric integer value of 2022.

As this is still error prone and a little tedious, [using XPath as michi suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557748/367456) is more elegant here.